# Differences for creating a set using set() or {}

Tags: python

This difference is confusing me:

```
>>> s = "()())()"
>>> print set(s)

set([')', '('])

>>> print {s}

set(['()())()'])
```

Why?

Comment: One is a set of characters, the other a set of strings.

Comment: which is which?

Comment: The `set()` constructor takes an iterable. An string is an iterable, so when you pass the constructor a single string it will iterate over it and each element (i.e. letter) to the set. If you don't want that behavior, pass in a tuple with the single string: `set((s,))`

Answer (score 15):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) for the `set()` method:

> Return a new [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) object, optionally with elements taken from iterable.

Since a string is an iterable, the `set()` method creates a set of all characters in the given string. However, since sets do not allow for  duplicate values, the output is a set containing the two unique characters in the string: `')'` and `'('`.

On the other hand, the shorthand syntax `{s}` creates a set out of all items between the curly brackets. Since you only inserted one item `s` (your string), the output was a set containing only that one item.

Answer (score 7):

When you write:

```
set(s)
```

it treats the string as an iterable, and makes a set containing its elements. The elements of a string are the individual characters. So it's equivalent to doing:

```
{'(', ')', '(', ')', ')', '(', ')'}
```

Since a set can't contain duplicate elements, you get a set with the two unique characters `'('` and `')'`.

However, when you write:

```
{s}
```

it just makes a set whose element is the value of the variable. The `{}` syntax treats each variable as a single element, rather than iterating over it.

The `set()` function is frequently used to convert from one kind of collection to a set of its elements, that's why it iterates over it.

Comment: Correction: it treats the string as an **iterable**

Answer (score 6):

`set()` takes an iterable as parameter, whose items will be the elements of the set.

So, set('my string') will contain each character of the iterable I passed it, that is {'m', 'y' ...}

Using `{}`, you create the set by writing down each of its elements, separated by commas.

{'my string'} contains one element, the string 'my string'

Answer (score 2):

Because the first one:

```
print set(s)
```

Is simply removing duplicates from the string,

But the second one:

```
print {s}
```

Is simply just storing the string in the `set`, so `set` with one element is always gonna be one element.

To make the the same result (it could be easier in python 3):

```
print {i for i in s}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first creates a set which contains only unique values, i.e (). While the other is a string which is what you defined s to be