# Python performance comparison for creating sets - set() vs. {} literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, set

A discussion following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918325/differences-for-creating-set-using-set-or/) left me wondering, so I decided to run a few tests and compare the creation time of `set((x,y,z))` vs. `{x,y,z}` for creating sets in Python (I'm using Python 3.7).

I compared the two methods using `time` and `timeit`. 
Both were consistent* with the following results:

```
test1 = """
my_set1 = set((1, 2, 3))
"""
print(timeit(test1))
```

*Result: 0.30240735499999993*

```
test2 = """
my_set2 = {1,2,3}
"""
print(timeit(test2))
```

*Result: 0.10771795900000003*

So the second method was **almost 3 times faster** than the first. 
This was quite a surprising difference to me.
What is happening under the hood to optimize the performance of the set literal over the `set()` method in such a way? Which would be advisable for which cases?

**** Note:*** I only show the results of the `timeit` tests since they are averaged over many samples, and thus perhaps more reliable, but the results when testing with `time` showed similar differences in both cases.

---

**Edit:** I'm aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list) and though it answers certain aspects of my original question, it didn't cover all of it. Sets were not addressed in the question, and as **empty sets** do not have a literal syntax in python, I was curious how (if at all) set creation using a literal would differ from using the `set()` method. Also, I wondered how the handling of the *tuple parameter* in `set((x,y,z)` happens behind the scenes and what is its possible impact on runtime.
The great answer by coldspeed helped clear things up.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674083/why-is-it-possible-to-replace-sometimes-set-with/36674133#36674133

Comment: Yeah, empty set literals don't exist. Non-empty ones do, and you'll see that the answer given to the other question is largely applicable to yours. Let's hope nobody asks a question about tuple literals vs `tuple(...)`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The two questions are definitely related but I am not quite sure they are duplicates. That question does not address when set() is more appropriate than the literal construction/comprehension syntax, which seems to be the underlying X in this XY problem. I would not close this myself but I would not lose any sleep if it was closed.

Comment: This is, essentially, the same question as `[] vs list()`. The factors that make literal syntax faster are *exactly the same*.

Comment: Fun times with modern Python: It has an "empty `set` literal", the one-eyed monkey operator: `{*()}`. It uses unpacking generalizations with an empty `tuple` (which is a singleton on CPython, so no `tuple` construction actually occurs) to impose the necessary context so Python sees a `set` being constructed, rather than a `dict`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's awesome, I had no idea. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(This is in response to code that has now been edited out of the initial question) You forgot to call the functions in the second case. Making the appropriate modifications, the results are as expected:

```
test1 = """
def foo1():
     my_set1 = set((1, 2, 3))
foo1()
"""    
timeit(test1)
# 0.48808742000255734
```

```
test2 = """
def foo2():
    my_set2 = {1,2,3}
foo2()
"""    
timeit(test2)
# 0.3064506609807722
```

---

Now, the reason for the difference in timings is because `set()` is a function call requiring a lookup into the symbol table, whereas the `{...}` set construction is an artefact of the syntax, and is much faster.

The difference is obvious when observing the disassembled byte code.

```
import dis

dis.dis("set((1, 2, 3))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
              2 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2, 3))
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
dis.dis("{1, 2, 3}")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BUILD_SET                3
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

In the first case, a function call is made by the instruction `CALL_FUNCTION` on the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` (which also comes with its own overhead, although minor—it is loaded as a constant via `LOAD_CONST`), whereas in the second instruction is just a `BUILD_SET` call, which is more efficient.

Re: your question regarding the time taken for tuple construction, we see this is actually negligible:

```
timeit("""(1, 2, 3)""")
# 0.01858693000394851

timeit("""{1, 2, 3}""")
# 0.11971827200613916
```

Tuples are immutable, so the compiler optimises this operation by loading it as a constant—this is called [constant folding](https://faster-cpython.readthedocs.io/optimizations.html#constant-folding) (you can see this clearly from the `LOAD_CONST` instruction above), so the time taken is negligible. This is not seen with sets are they are mutable (Thanks to @user2357112 for pointing this out).

---

For larger sequences, we see similar behaviour. `{..}` syntax is faster at constructing sets using set comprehensions as opposed to `set()` which has to build the set from a generator.

```
timeit("""set(i for i in range(10000))""", number=1000)
# 0.9775058150407858

timeit("""{i for i in range(10000)}""", number=1000)
# 0.5508635920123197
```

For reference, you can also use iterable unpacking on more recent versions:

```
timeit("""{*range(10000)}""", number=1000)
# 0.7462548640323803
```

Interestingly, however, `set()` is faster when called directly on `range`:

```
timeit("""set(range(10000))""", number=1000)
# 0.3746800610097125
```

This happens to be faster than the set construction. You will see similar behaviour for other sequences (such as `list`s).

My recommendation would be to use the `{...}` set comprehension when constructing set literals, and as an alternative to passing a generator comprehension to `set()`; and instead use `set()` to convert an existing sequence/iterable to a set.

Comment: He is also creating a tuple and then pass it to the set function, does the tuple creation times count?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Perhaps, but I cannot be sure. In this case, maybe not as I believe python interns (caches) tuples, so after the first couple of timeits that might not cause much of a difference in timings. But in theory, yes, it will contribute.

Comment: Whoops! Silly me, that definitely explains it.
Editing the question, the first part is still rather intruiging, I'd love a more in depth view of what's happening.
Was also wondering about what @DanielMesejo asked.

Comment: @DanielMesejo might be wrong but from the bytecode, it seems it does not create the tuple, it is built as a constant when python code is initially parsed. It just `LOAD_CONST`s the tuple. The overhead comes after, building the set from that tuple.

Comment: @spectras You're right, that actually proves the point that the tuple is cached after the initial call.

Comment: Regarding your tuple edit, it is ~6 times faster. I don't know if that's negligible in context, but that is interesting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Actually `set()` is not specifically optimized for `range` (at least I can't find any from a quick glance at the code). It is probably just that using an iterator directly is faster than the comprehension which needs an extra layer of abstraction. Additionally, `{*range(10000)}` is as fast as `set(range(10000))`, although I personally prefer the latter style.

Comment: @infmagic2047 I should've clarified, set is optimized for readily available iterables (read: not generators). My tests indicate that unpacking is about 2x slower than calling set() and not being relevant to the discussion did not add it in, although I could.

Comment: @coldspeed What python version are you testing on? I get no speed difference in both 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: Python doesn't intern the `(1, 2, 3)` tuple. You're looking at constant folding, not interning.

Comment: @user2357112 Why is the same thing not done with `{1, 2, 3}`? Or is constant folding also done here, but with larger overhead?

Comment: @infmagic2047 I tested this on my 2013 mac using python3.6. I've added a timeit test for this.

Comment: @coldspeed: `{1, 2, 3}` is mutable.

Comment: @user2357112 Can't believe it was that simple. Learned something new (and made appropriate edits), thank you!

Comment: @coldspeed: Note: If you use the `set` literal of literals as the right hand side of the `in` keyword (e.g. looping `for x in {1,2,3}:` or membership tests a la `if 1 in {1, 2, 3}:`), it will do constant folding, storing a `frozenset` version of the set in the function's array of constants. It can do this because those operations can't mutate the set (barring insane reflection/inspection nonsense), so freezing a copy and reusing it is plausible. Pure implementation detail (Python 2 didn't do this for instance, changed in one of the Python 3 releases).