# Why is initializing a set in python as `{*()}` faster than `set()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, benchmarking, python-internals

I was interested in finding the fastest way to initialize an empty set in Python (I'm using 3.8). You cannot instantiate an empty set as `{}` as that creates a `dict`, so what is generally recommended is to use the `set()` constructor. I noticed the other day that there is another way to instantiate an empty set: you can unpack an empty tuple `()` into the `{...}` syntax for sets as follows: `{*()}`. Timing this with the `timeit` module in `ipython` gives the following results:

```py
%timeit {*()}
67.7 ns ± 1.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit set()
84.5 ns ± 2.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I find this pretty peculiar - the more elegant `set()` constructor takes 25% more time relative to `{*()}`. The same observations have been made in the past with, e.g., `[]` vs. `list()` and `{}` vs. `dict()`.

```py
%timeit []
17.8 ns ± 0.791 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
%timeit list()
81 ns ± 1.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit {}
18.6 ns ± 0.575 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
%timeit dict()
98.6 ns ± 5.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

It is rather easy to switch to the primitive syntax `{}` and `[]` for `list`s and `dict`s, but what I've found for sets is obviously not as clean. I'm curious as to insights into this (in general).

Comment: This performance differences are so small that for all intents and purposes, just use what you find the most readable. But this is likely the result of function-call overhead, which is rather large for Python.

Comment: In general I completely agree. In certain algorithms, I can see nontrivial speedup - but this is more about my curiosity about the internals than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("{*()}")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (())
              2 BUILD_SET_UNPACK         1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("set()")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Two things are faster, here.

First, `set` requires a global lookup, `LOAD_NAME` which is usually two hash-lookups (one in the global namespace and one in the builtins namespace). Then there is the function call, which is expensive in Python.

Compare this to the `LOAD_CONST` which is a quick, single, array indexing operation, and `BUILD_SET_UNPACK` which is a specialized, set-building instruction. No doubt it does what the `set` constructor does eventually, but basically here you end up using a byte-code level short-cut).

In any case, for all intents in purposes, stick with the more readable `set()`.

Answer (score 2):

I find that staring at the details that close tends to result in misleading conclusions.

If you actually do something with the result, `set()` is faster.

For example:

```
from timeit import timeit


def do_literal():
    s = {*()}
    s.add(1)


def do_function():
    s = set()
    s.add(1)


print(timeit(do_literal, number=100000000))
print(timeit(do_function, number=100000000))
```

Results:

```
14.3875497
13.313828099999998
```

Why the difference occurs is another interesting question, but perhaps not for SO (and I certainly don't know the answer).

Comment: Very good point. Although, I suspect, if you want to do *a lot of little things* the performance will be about equal.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the intial capacity of the resulting set, the set constructor is tuned for a capacity that will allow several additions efficiently, whereas the literal version is tuned for allowing the smallest excess capacity. Maybe try comparing `set()` vs `set(())`. I'd be interested to see the results.

Comment: A similar example, `[None]*n` will create a list where there is no overallocation of the inital buffer, so the first `.append` to it will be slow, because it will require a re-allocation of that buffer. However, `[None for _ in range(n)]` will likely result in a buffer that is over-allocated, so `.append` will be very fast.

Comment: This is a very interesting test! I am getting at what @juanpa.arrivillaga is saying - there are many cases where empty containers exist for the purpose of, e.g. valid comparisons, placeholders, etc., and may not ever be populated with items - so no pre-allocation is necessary

Answer (score 1):

`set()` is a function call that requires a lookup into the symbol table, while a set construction literal is an "artifact of the syntax". It's especially visible with a peer into the byte code.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977997/python-performance-comparison-for-creating-sets-set-vs-literal#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20the%20reason%20for%20the,observing%20the%20disassembled%20byte%20code.) for a more in-depth answer

Answer (score 1):

I am speculating that, similarly to the case of `dict()` vs `{}` and `list` vs `[]` it has a different structure that involves function calls. See the output of `dis`:

```
import dis
>>> dis.dis('set()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (set)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('{*()}')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (())
              2 BUILD_SET_UNPACK         1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Function calls in Python are expensive as they [have high extra overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893139/why-is-a-function-method-call-in-python-expensive).