# What is the difference between set() and {}?

Tags: python

What is the difference between this two expressions?

```
x = set(1) # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
x = {1}    # OK
```

Why does the first raise an error and the other not?

Comment: Both create sets. The constructor function expects to be passed an iterable (as the error indicates). See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: This might help too, first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918325/differences-for-creating-set-using-set-or

Comment: Also, note same apply for other constructors like e.g. `list(1)` and `[1]`, and `tuple(1)` and `(1,)`